# Spring: How do I call a method only when in web application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a module with name "CacheService" which do some cache works, it has a method named "preheatCache" which build cache content when started. The "CacheService" referenced by both web application server and task application server. The web server and task serve started independently, when the task server started, I don't want "preheatCache" executed. How could I implement this?

the code in CacheService that call preheatCache automatically when start server:

```
@EventListener(ContextRefreshedEvent.class)
  public void afterStartup() {
    preheatCache();
  }

private preheatCache(){
    // build cache content
}
```

the event triggered both in web server and task server.

I trid `@ConditionalOnWebApplication` like this

```
@ConditionalOnWebApplication
private preheatCache(){
 // build cache content
}
```

but it seems not work

Is there some annotation or Spring's mechanism which act on a method, make this method only called in web server?

Comment: It must be public method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be a public method to allow AOP to kick in

```
@ConditionalOnWebApplication
public void preheatCache(){
 // build cache content
}
```

and must NOT be invoked from bean itself - so you must self inject that bean and use injection for invocation

```
@Autowired
private BeanContainingThatMethod self;

    @EventListener(ContextRefreshedEvent.class)
      public void afterStartup() {
        self.preheatCache();
      }
```

If I were you I would create dedicated bean for that (unless this is the one) and annotate whole bean. This way whole bean will be created and managed only if web context is present and will be skipped from creation otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You could register a seperate bean with the `@ConditionalOnWebApplication`, so that it is only registered when the webapplication is running. Then this bean could have your `CacheService` injected and call your preheatCache method. This additional bean could look like this:

```
@Component
@ConditionalOnWebApplication
public class CachePreheater
{
   private CacheService cacheService;

   public CachePreheater(CacheService cacheService) {
      this.cacheService = cacheService;
   }

   @EventListener(ContextRefreshedEvent.class)
   public void afterStartup() {
     this.cacheService.preheatCache();
   }
}
```

For this code to work you have to adjust the visibility of your preheatCache method.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach, you can maintain two profiles for web, task-server.

You could manually initialize it like below.

```
@Service
public class CacheService {

    @Profile("web")
    @PostConstruct
    public void pstConstruct(){
        this.preheatCache()
    }

    private preheatCache(){
    // build cache content
    }
}
```

In Profile annotation you can use any boolean property value like ${property.value} and use it for different use cases.